# How to sort the expression not based on the Heads in Times?

Tags: sorting

Is there any way i can sort the following expression ?

```
a[k, l] b[i, j]
```

so that i would have:

```
b[i, j] a[k,l]
```

Mathematica does the ordering based on the heads. is there anyway to change it ?

Comment: To be clear: you are seeking a way to sort the elements of that expression based on the lexicographical ordering of the arguments to those elements ?

Comment: @High Performance Mark i want to order the expression based on their arguments rather than the heads. so if i have a[m,n] b[i,j] c[k,l] i want it to be like b[i,j] c[k,l] a[m,n]

Comment: The expression you show here has head `Times`: spaces are interpreted as multiplication (use `FullForm` to check if you're unsure). `Times` is a symbol with the attribute `Orderless`, meaning that it will always sort its arguments in canonical order. The only way to have something close to what you want is `Inactivate[b[i, j] a[k, l], Times]`

Comment: `Inactive[Times] @@ SortBy[List @@ expr, First]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with the help of Bob Hanlon:

```
axx = HoldForm[
   NonCommutativeMultiply @@ 
    SortBy[List @@ (a[k, l] b[i, j]), First]] // ReleaseHold

axx //. NonCommutativeMultiply[a_, Y___] :> HoldForm[Times[a, Y]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SortBy[Inactivate[a[m, n] b[i, j] c[k, l], Times], Function[x, #[[x]]]/@ Range[Length@#]&] /.
  Inactive[Times] -> HoldForm@*Times
```

> b[i,j] c[k,l] a[m,n]